# rails results page value from search page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, pagination

I have a search form using `:method => 'get'` which is very similar to my `index.html.erb` file. I have set up a route to a results page but @user defined in the controller under the action result, is the same in the results page as the original @user from index which contains all. I am wondering how to get the values from my search form?

If someone can point me in a direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please, provide controller code

Comment: your question is very unclear from the information you provided. Can you share your controller codes and if possible specific route file's codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need to define a route for your search, but as you have already done it. Next step is to write your search form in your desired view:

```
<%= form_tag(custom_search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

This will get the search text, and send you in `params[:search]` variable, that you can access in your controller in the method that you put in the route. Next you need to define a class-level search method on your model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(text)
    where("column LIKE ?", "%#{text}%")
  end
end
```

And then, in your controller, you can do something like:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @result = Model.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing params[:search]